# How to assign color values to an unknown number of elements?

Tags: css, sass

I've got 7 color values and I want to set them as background color for an unknown number of `div` elements. I'm using `Sass` but can't figure out how to do it. Basically what I want is to go through these color value one by one and assign it to the `div` if there are more `div`'s than colors then I will continue with the first color until I don't have any `div`s.

Any ideas? I'm quite new to `Sass` and reading through the documentation didn't help me, though I probably have to use a function and a loop I guess.

Comment: nth-child(7n + x) could be usable here, but no code

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by first creating a variable with your list of desired colours inside; and then making a loop to go through each colour and set it as the background image. This will go through each colour one by one and then start again from the first colour should it have to.

```css
div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

$bgColors: red, green, blue;

@for $i from 1 through length($bgColors) {
 div:nth-child(#{length($bgColors)}n+#{$i}) {
  background: nth($bgColors, $i);
 }
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```

[SASS Solution JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev19jx5p/)

Comment: The sass solution is 100% correct, but I don't see any reason anyone would ever do this with jQuery (or javascript for that matter), and the op specifically asked for Sass. Even without sass, this is easy enough to do with vanilla css. Vote up for the good Sass tho.